# Error with Bevel tool

Tags: modeling, error, bevel

So I'm trying to bevel edges on a loop and it keeps doing this.
[image]

The loop has 55 edges.

Comment: There's almost certainly some corrupt geometry in there, somewhere. Remove the bevel, H hide a few faces, have a look around for doubles.

Comment: Also check for internal faces.